# Docker-compose up --detach : No space left on device

Tags: docker, ssh, docker-compose, directory

I'm trying to launch a new release of my application using docker but i have this new error when i run the'docker-compose up --detach --scale app=3' command :

ERROR: for cc5610c2dbea_talent_redis_1  Cannot start service redis: mkdir /var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/moby/cc5610c2dbeae94427d0611e66d106aba7e4bf86e74b6a1147b0012e25403058: no space left on device: unknown

Starting a9fdab601f28_talent_proxy_1 ... error
vice: unknown

ERROR: for a9fdab601f28_talent_proxy_1  Cannot start service proxy: mkdir /var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/moby/a9fdab601f2877f16be4f81744b166938f93df2143bf66a7bc6c8cef372dd38a: no space left on device: unknown

ERROR: for redis  Cannot start service redis: mkdir /var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/moby/cc5610c2dbeae94427d0611e66d106aba7e4bf86e74b6a1147b0012e25403058: no space left on device: unknown

ERROR: for app  Cannot start service app: mkdir /var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/moby/4ae9a1cf124c3c96b1a6841a84f3cefaff415e76c9fb9608fa5eccb87c892a79: no space left on device: unknown

ERROR: for proxy  Cannot start service proxy: mkdir /var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/moby/a9fdab601f2877f16be4f81744b166938f93df2143bf66a7bc6c8cef372dd38a: no space left on device: unknown

I have already cleaned the docker images folder removing the olders images but the error is the same.

What is the problem ? I don't want to remove my mongodb and redis database

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

docker system prune -a -f and free up some space
then check
df -h
df -i

Comment: Same problem, ERROR: for proxy Cannot start service proxy: mkdir /var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/moby/a9fdab601f2877f16be4f81744b166938f93df2143bf66a7bc6c8cef372dd38a: no space left on device: unknown

Comment: This command doesn't remove my mongo database ?

Answer (score 0):

As per the message there is no space left in the device to start docker container services
you have to delete some files
you may also try removing dangling volume if exists using the command

```
docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -qf dangling=true)
```